# What is the appropriate test for repeated measures with categorical(nominal )outcomes?

Tags: categorical-data

I have two groups of patients undergoing different treatments (active versus placebo), followed up at 3 different time points (time 1, time 2, time 3). The outcomes are categorical (improvement vs no improvement) so I know I should not use repeated-measures ANOVA. What is the appropriate test to use? I use SPSS for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

A generalized linear mixed model is appropriate, binomial distribution and logit link. Your response is essentially binary (1 or 0) improved or did not. I would use a fixed effects of treatment (placebo or not) , time period and their interaction. Random effect of  patient. This can be used to assess the probability of improvement or not, accounting  for repeat measures on a patient.

I use r and sas, but below is a helpful link.

**link for how to do glmm's in spss**

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/components/glmm/glmm_cablesurvey_howto.html

*you want to select binary logistic instead of multinomial*

Goodluck!

Answer (score -2):

We can use [chi-square tes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test). We use this test to see if there is any relationship between two categorical variables.  In SPSS chi-square tes is called  [chisq](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/whatstat/whatstat.htm#chisq)

Comment: Perhaps I couldn't make my point clear in the previous question. I used mixed model ANOVA for comparison of continuous variables at three time points.  Now I want to make comparison of proportions improved between the two groups of treatment at time 2 and time 3. Should I make this comparison separately at time 2 and time 3 using  chi-square test?